# How do you remove a dimension in a Google Data Studio report?

Tags: looker-studio

How do you remove an obsolete column from a GDS PostgreSQL-based report?

I updated my base SQL to remove some columns, but when I click the "Fields->" button to list all columns, it still lists the removed columns/dimensions. And for some reason that I can't determine, the  "Remove" option is disabled so I can't even manually remove them

This is a huge problem/bug because if I then click "Create Report", it throws an error message, presumably because it's trying to access a column that no longer exists in my base SQL.

[image: screenshot of unremovable dimension]

Am I missing something there, or is this just a buggy interface? How do I remove a dimension?

Answer (score 1):

I can remove dimensions and metric by clicking in the right side of the green container, right next to the ellipsis.

[image: Dimension section]

Comment: Doesn't work for me - right clicking just brings up the usual Chrome right click options

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you add/remove any column/field in the data source.  You need to click `Refresh Fields` to refresh data source fields.

When you refresh data source fields:

***Removed fields in the data set are removed from the data source*.**

For more details, visit Data Studio official [documentation on Refresh data source fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7083608?hl=en).

[image]